# Manipulate React form over DevTools console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've to fill some React forms on a website. Therefore, I've tried to write a JavaScript script to autofill the textareas to check the checkboxes and so on at the React forms by pasting the script into the Chrome Dev Tools console. Everything looks good first, but first the send button is still disabled and my input is not recognized or diapered.

With "normal" forms, this kind of injections works like a charm, but what do I've to do with react forms that react recognize the fields are filled?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With "normal" forms it works because it's directly to the DOM, and for React won't work because React uses VirtualDOM.

Can you try to modify your code to use `useRef` from React?

https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs

Comment: It doesn't work:

import { useRef } from 'react';

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module